# vue update form input value one time without v-model etc

Tags: vue.js

New to vue, looking to update html form email value from ? to api result one time only...

I can't use v-model as the submitted form validated with php so invalid submission will reset the submitted value to null etc..

```
<form method="post"action="/user/change/12345">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="?" id="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>        
</form>

getUser: function(id) {
            axios
                .get('/api/users/view.json?id=' + id)
                .then(function(response) {

                ???? update form email value with response.data.user.email;

                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
```

Comment: use a model then do basic validation clientside, like is it an email is it blank etc, post it with ajax and if it fails validation then show an error, you could reset it back to what it was if you store it in previous_email when you loads the user (normally this is done via the original value from a vuex store but you could simply have 2 models one unchanged one the working one)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you want.

See this to get started:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
const email = ref('')
const getUser = async () => {
  email.value = await fetch('https://random-data-api.com/api/users/random_user').then(res => res.json()).then(json => json.email)
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="getUser">
    Click to get email
  </button>
  <form method="post" action="/user/change/12345">
    <input type="text" name="email" :value="email" id="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>        
  </form>
</template>
```

[Playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Instead of `:value` you can use the `v-model` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, ended up using plain getElementById for now...

```
<form method="post"action="/user/change/12345">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>        
</form>

    getUser: function(id) {
        axios
            .get('/api/users/view.json?id=' + id)
            .then(function(response) {

            document.getElementById("email").value = response.data.user.email;

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

You can manipulate the value of an input via ref.

First, set the ref attribute in your template.

```html
<input type="text" name="email" value="?" id="email" ref="emailField"/>
```

Then, you can access this element via `this.$refs` in your script section.

```js
getUser () {
  // above code...
  this.$refs.emailField.value = response.data.user.email
}
```